# The full text doesn't want to stay in the dialog window

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am creating an editable description table and I need the original input to stay in the dialog box after I activate it with the "Edit" button. For now only the first word of the original description stays in the box.

I have even tried adding the `originalValue` constant that would replace the changed value and when I debug in the console, I see that the replacement is successful - but not in the front-end.

How to fix this?

```js
function edit_description() {
    var targetDescription = $("#description-1");
    var value = targetDescription.text();
    const originalValue = targetDescription.text();

    targetDescription.html(`<input class="description form-control" data-target="description-1" type="text" value=${value}>`);

    $("input:text").focus();

    if (value != "") {
      value = originalValue
    };

    $("input").blur(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var target = targetDescription.children('input').attr("data-target");
      $(`#${target}`).text($(this).val());
      var description = $(this).val();
      save_description(identification = "description-1", description);
    });
  };
  function save_description(identification, description){
    console.log('Saved!');

    var userInput = {"identification":identification, "description":description};
  };
```

```css
a[role="button"][onclick] {
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/base.css" />
  </head>

  <body>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <div class="table-wrapper">
      <table id="table" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col"><span>Edit</span></th>
            <th scope="col"><span>Description</span></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td id = "edit-1"><a class="btn" role="button" onclick="edit_description();">Edit ></a></td>
            <td id = "description-1">Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: By doing with the content of the `value` attribute, what you did with the values of all other attributes in that line - wrap it in double quotes as _attribute delimiters_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the value attribute from your html string and set the input value via jquery:

```
        targetDescription.html(`<input class="description form-control" data-target="description-1" type="text">`);
        $("input:text").val(value);
        $("input:text").focus();
```

You can also simply add quotes around `${value}`. The problem is that without the quote marks, when jquery parses in the value, the result looks like this `value=Lorem ipsum dolor>` and so when the browser parser hits the white space, it thinks your value is done and ignores the rest, or treats the rest as attributes. So you can do this:

```
targetDescription.html(`<input class="description form-control" data-target="description-1" type="text" value="${value}">`);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I like the second solution better, since it highlights the text too.
Your answer is great, because it is very comprehensive!